# Add libraries from npm in root sage 8.5.3

Tags: node.js, wordpress, google-maps, npm, roots-sage

Adding libraries from npm in root sage 8.5.3, I got error in console with required not found.

```
var GoogleMapsLoader = require('google-maps');
              GoogleMapsLoader.load(function(google) {
                new google.maps.Map(el, options);
            });
```

Note: I add that code on main.js using sage 8.5.3 but the code says require not found in my console

Comment: Could you share more code and a full error you're getting?

Comment: Are you experiencing this with any other packages?

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm that is the correct name? You can search for it on [the official NPM website](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=google-maps).